# Button format becomes disorganized when screen size is reduced

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've included a snippet below. If you run the snippet at full screen, you'll see the effect I want (buttons 1 and 2 on the left, and 3 and 4 on the right). However when you make the window smaller, buttons 1 and 2 move to the right and above button 3 and 4, which move to the left.

I could fix this with media queries but I think it would be better to just figure out what I can do to fix this without them.

```css
#lower-bar {
  background-color: #0F6292;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
}
.center-left {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(40%, 70%);
}
.center-center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(25%, 70%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section id='lower-bar'>
  <div class='row'>

    <div class='col-md-6'>
      <div class='center-left'>
        <input type="button" id='btn-1' class=" btn c-btn-quiz" value="1">
        <input type="button" id='btn-2' class=" btn c-btn-quiz" value="2">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='col-md-6'>
      <div class='center-center'>
        <input type="button" id='3' class="btn c-btn-quiz" value="3">
        <input type="button" id="4" class="btn c-btn-quiz" value="4">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this changes to your codes,

```
#lower-bar {
  background-color: #0F6292;
  width:100%;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
}
.center-left {
  width:50%;
  height:auto;
  float:left;
  margin-top:30px;
 }

.center-center {
  width:50%;
  height:auto;
  float:left;
  margin-top:30px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help because it seems like you could greatly simplfy this by using `pull-right` and `pull-left` is this is to remain the same across viewports. See [Quick Floats](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats)

```css
#lower-bar {
  background-color: #0F6292;
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="lower-bar">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="pull-left">
      <input type="button" id="btn-1" class="btn c-btn-quiz" value="1">
      <input type="button" id="btn-2" class="btn c-btn-quiz" value="2">
    </div>

    <div class="pull-right">
      <input type="button" id="3" class="btn c-btn-quiz" value="3">
      <input type="button" id="4" class="btn c-btn-quiz" value="4">
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would to use flex boxes.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<section id='lower-bar'>
<div class='row'>
        <div class='center-left'>
            <input type="button" id='btn-1' class=" btn c-btn-quiz" value="1">
            <input type="button" id='btn-2' class=" btn c-btn-quiz" value="2">
        </div>

        <div class='center-center'>
            <input type="button" id='3' class="btn c-btn-quiz" value="3">
            <input type="button" id="4" class="btn c-btn-quiz" value="4">
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css

```
#lower-bar {
     background-color: #0F6292;
    display: flex;
    }
    .row {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .center-left {
     display: flex;
    margin-left: 25%;
    }

    .center-left input {
        margin-left: 2px;
        margin-right: 2px;
    }

    .center-center {
       display: flex;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: 25%;
    }

    .center-center input {
        margin-left: 2px;
        margin-right: 2px;
    }
```